# SPServices - Local and offline

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, spservices, offline

I'm using SPServices in my web applications deployed in Sharepoint and viewed through a content editor webpart.

This SharePoint solution is not possible for me to access without VPN, so I'm regularly going in to download all the list content with SPServices into an XML file and when I open the web applications locally, its knows that it's not in Sharepoint and then uses the XML file for data delivery.

Now my solution only doesn't take any notice to CAML-OPTIONS or CAML-QUERIES, when getting data locally, I just use jQuery.AJAX to get it. This has been fine, until now.

I have a larger application, where I have a LOT more data and I need to review it all locally, so I need the calm options/queries to work.

Have anyone encountered the same issue and have a solution on how to work locally with saved list data?

Comment: What about storing your data into your browser with one of the many javascript offline databases that exist? You can download, then store your lists locally and query them. You'll have to adapt your code to have specific requests depending if you are online (caml) or offline.

Comment: I presume you mean CAML, if not, what are CALM-OPTIONS?

Comment: @AymKdn can't use the browser local storage, because its 2 different computers I have for developing and viewing the sharepoint site. Today I just save the XML response to an XML file .

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes, sorry - corrected

Comment: CAML is all processed server-side by SP, So you would have to rebuilt that logic

Comment: So, right now, you transfer the xml file from one computer to another?

Comment: @AymKdn yes :) thats right

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Exactly, but I didn't want to create the logic myself, if somebody else already did that. I have tried google - a lot - but haven't found any usefull results yet.

Comment: You would be rebuilding a language that has been  in SharePoints core for a very long time... All ServerSide.. Modern way is to do a REST call (which also can do Server Side OData operations) and proces your dataset Client-Side with JS

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just storing the XML you get back from a SOAP call via SPServices. You could use SPGetListItemsJson instead and save the data as JSON, which would probably save you some storage - depending on the data.

I do something similar (staying in SharePoint) to cache data to help get around the 5000 item limit in REST. You can just read in the entire JSON file and then filter it on the client. It would make no sense to try to replicate CAML.

Comment: I agree, its a LARGE task! This is why I'm trying to figure out how other people has done this. I can't be the first to create a development version before adding it to SharePoint :)

Thanks for the note about using the getListItemsJson instead - I will defiantly try that!

Comment: Marc D Anderson **===** Mr SPServices; if there was a way he would know..